# How to remove precision part of money datatype in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have some data in money column, database is postgrsql, by default two decimal digits are coming in select query result, I can truncate or replace last three chars to achieve my goal, Is there any function or other efficient way to do it.

```
select mycolumn from mytable;
output is $256,352.00
output should be $256,352
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: the `money` data type has many quirks and disadvantages. It's better to use `numeric` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it to a numeric type, then you can use the [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) function to format the value:

```
select to_char(mycolumn::numeric, '$FM999,999')
from mytable
```

`to_char()` gives you a wide range of formatting options. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html) for details.

Comment: one downside of this approach is that ORDER BY will return a text sort, not a numeric sort.

Comment: @MaxHodges: you can still sort by the underlying column